# Animations in React

Tags: reactjs, animation

I am trying to create animation effects on my react project. kindly recommend good libraries for that. i am trying to create different animation effects such as ease in, bouncing, loading screen and a lot more

Comment: Asking for library etc. suggestions is off-topic for StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use react-spring for animation ui.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spring
```